# Same body parameters in Postman and RestTemplate's API call but only Postman works

Tags: java, spring-boot, spotify

My app that consumes Spotify's API was working normally until some days ago, however, suddenly it tells me that one of the body parameter I'm using is wrong (the same that was working before).
I've tested this same parameter in Postman and it works just fine:
[Postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXpZw.jpg)

Body parameters that is generating error:
grant_type: authorization_code

Response message i'm getting:

```
400 Bad Request
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "grant_type must be client_credentials, authorization_code or refresh_token"
}
```

I've put an interceptor to check if the call I was making truly had the right paramenter and it really shows correctly.

Code I'm using:

Rest call

```
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", CLIENT_ID_SECRET);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("grant_type", "authorization_code"); //parameter generating the error
        map.add("code", CODE);
        map.add("redirect_uri", "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity=
                new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

        try{
            AccessToken accessToken = template.postForObject("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/", requestEntity,  AccessToken.class);
        }
        catch(RestClientResponseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Fail " + e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }
```

Interceptor result:

```
2019-08-29 23:37:44.660  INFO 18784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.d.helper.LoggingRequestInterceptor   : URI         : https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/
2019-08-29 23:37:44.664  INFO 18784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.d.helper.LoggingRequestInterceptor   : Method      : POST
2019-08-29 23:37:44.665  INFO 18784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.d.helper.LoggingRequestInterceptor   : Headers     : [Accept:"application/json, application/*+json", Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", Authorization:"Basic M2JjZDNmMDVmYTBiNDVkOWE4MTY4ZmFmMjNhYj...DdiMmJjODg=", Content-Length:"433"]
2019-08-29 23:37:44.666  INFO 18784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.d.helper.LoggingRequestInterceptor   : Request body: grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQCTD5keYruiGP1ukaZYhDcC0tu9eLnvPnt3IYGlk7mfyaMIPEtdAiTCGbJOfpFA0v9-kgDJJysMAfTnx2e76AHbOZ2C55WVMtYvrR88t6_MDAkbLaPI_0NK7u8AqWhfj1zrkUz-3PBVwoPs6PduuqucSJporVEedpdcNGuQ24HjJdBxjQNEuBwGeTIllBkaWZSx6RzKoZcU-IPw5M44EbCwvHOtZiWL4U5nzER3NPCiZ9_r_w__wmFW1-HunE-32Q1lBzNz9vJVvsl3X_vumBHCNCAWdITzAmiUdU34RHRQAnyimKMPsnPYA-fd1Y_a47e2EXCJclgTHgm6-ODEXmZB&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.getpostman.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback
```

Api documentation: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorizaton-code-flow

I have no idea what to test anymore, really appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

I've found the problem,
I was making the request to https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/
Deleting the final / worked (https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token).
most likely it was changed as making request to other endpoints with / in the end as https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/ still works...

Comment: Didn't you upgrade some library in you application? Spring Boot version is the same as few days before?

Comment: No, nothing changed at all, I even tried a previous version to make sure

Comment: Thanks so much for your post and solution with the Edit. I've encountered the same issue with that same endpoint. One moment it is working, next minute its not. I never would have guessed to remove the trailing `/`. You've saved me time and even more frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I have signed in and created an app in `Spotify`. Please find the below source which is working fine for me. I am not able to find any error in your source.

#### Authorization

https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=_clientId&scope=user-read-private&redirect_uri=http://localhost:11001/api/spotify-response

#### Token

```
@GetMapping("/spotify-response")
public void spotifyResponse(@RequestParam String code, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    String _clientId = "5eb8ce6ea7d04*******e870c48f";
    String _clientSecret = "d45470deea224********3d8ab9";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    String usernamePassword = _clientId+":"+_clientSecret;
    String basicToken = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(usernamePassword.getBytes());
    httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "Basic "+basicToken);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    requestBody.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    requestBody.add("code", code.trim());
    requestBody.add("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:11001/api/spotify-response");

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, httpHeaders);
    try {
        Object response = restTemplate.postForObject("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", httpEntity, Object.class);
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) response;
        map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k+": "+v));
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
        String accessToken = (String) map.get("access_token");
        String patientId = (String) map.get("patient");
        String url = "http://localhost:4200/login-success?accessToken="+accessToken+"&patientId="+patientId;
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", url); // redirect to success page
    }
    catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

#### Console Output:

```
access_token: BQB9z1CeXwnS3MI0uQN-eAK9WRIW4r7U5k0H1RCxnRi5UlF04oYbcYgyoFH3wM-EQUydkKhXjhlJOposaoYSssQpcF9HgPHVCPiwNvzrHS5H8Cc64gcFlstAKxFDTMAfyUqfQ4UTBvdGfmQoORxoEhzsGCAcps-3fnoca_XdzLgjfJdPaQ
token_type: Bearer
expires_in: 3600
refresh_token: AQCKahUnfekyvGZ3RuO6h85YPSmhCqlRTklCw8r4RZzh8BesCu-4mVXKypsuTNV7AwE5tRJt8BXDn1eyXf797LvfVfN4Ju4KUc9AzYFKOiQPblUMip3_ImPOZDsF1InxIzjkAA
scope: user-read-private
```

Comment: Its good that you got it working. But please explain what the real question's answer was!

Comment: Huge thanks Alexpandiyan, this worked!  just makes me even more confused as why my code stopped working